# PHP exec() causing memory usage to stay high?

Tags: linux, memory, php, mysql, wordpress

I am quite new to using exec() command in php. I am using it along with this script called phantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/) to run a process which creates a pdf of my website's pages.

The problem is, when I run exec(), it usually finishes running the script in about 3~5 seconds. However sometimes the loading would go on forever, not finishing for more than 5 minutes. In these cases I just refresh the page (the script runs on page load). After doing this I check my memory usage in the CPanel and memory usage stays high as if the process is still running.

What could be causing this? I already set a set_time_limit(60) to kill any overtly-long running processes, but it just stays high. I have checked other probable causes but I am sure it has to do with this exec process.

FYI, the exec() triggers some mysql queries.

```
class Challenge_mealplanner_print extends Challenge_mealplanner {

 private function generate_personal_details_string($this_page_round_number, $week_number){
      return get_current_user_id().'-'.$this_page_round_number.'-'.$week_number;
 }

 function generate_personal_mealplanner_pdf($this_page_round_number, $week_number){
     $phantomjs_loc = escapeshellarg(realpath('').'/path/to/some/script');
     $mealplanner_gen_script_loc = escapeshellarg(realpath('').'/path/to/some/script');
     $mealplanner_print_page_uri = escapeshellarg('/path/to/some/script'.$this->generate_personal_details_string($this_page_round_number, $week_number));
     $pdf_file_name = escapeshellarg('Mealplan-'.$this_page_round_number.'-'.$week_number.'.pdf');

     unset($this_page_round_number, $week_number);

     $result = exec( $phantomjs_loc.' '.$mealplanner_gen_script_loc.' '.$mealplanner_print_page_uri.' '.$pdf_file_name.' A4 2>&1');
     return $result;
 }
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Update - I checked the Process Manager in my webhost manager and my fears were confirmed true - there were 8 processes started by this exec() command that have not stopped. Even though the memory usage of these processes were showing as 0, when I killed them all the memory usage went right down. I guess the thing to work out for me is, how do I make sure these processes are killed and not made to linger. Would putting die() or exit() at the end of the script do it?